# Solving for rotation matrix: Aligning vector a with vector b and then rotating around vector b

Tags: quadcopter, matlab, rotation

Currently working on a quadcopter simulation. I have a desired thrust vector,

```
t =sin(30)cos(45)a1+sin(30)sin(45)a2+cos(30)a3
```

and desired yaw angle,

```
psi = 45.
```

Because we are working with an under-actuated system, I am trying to solve for the rotation matrix that aligns the vector:b3 = [0,0,1] (direction of thrust in the body-fixed frame of reference) with the direction of t. Here is my code:

```
t = [sind(30) * cosd(45), sind(30) * sind(45), cosd(30)];

b3 = [0;0;1];

psi = 45;

syms phi theta; 

eqn = [[cosd(psi)*cosd(theta)-sind(phi)*sind(psi)*sind(theta), - 
cosd(phi)*sind(psi), cosd(psi)*sind(theta)+cosd(theta)*sind(phi)*sind(phi);
cosd(theta)*sind(psi)+cosd(psi)*sind(phi)*sind(theta), cosd(phi)*cosd(psi), 
sind(psi)*sind(theta)-cosd(theta)*sind(phi)*cosd(psi);
 -cosd(phi)*sind(theta), sind(phi), cosd(phi)*cosd(theta)] 
* b3 == t/norm(t)];

S = solve(eqn,[phi theta]);
disp(S.phi)
disp(S.theta)`
```

The problem is that it outputs an empty symbolic struct, with no warnings or errors otherwise:
[image: Output]

What I am doing wrong? It is an issue with my theory, my implementation, or both?

Comment: I believe you have an error in your rotation matrix. Namely the upper right element contains sind(phi)*sind(phi). The rest of your rotation matrix looks like $Z_1\,X_2\,Y_3$ as [shown here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix), so instead of sind(phi)*sind(phi) I believe you should use sind(phi)*sind(psi).

Comment: Thank you. I believe this is correct, although was able to find an analytical solution which was much faster. Will post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analytic Solution:

```
t = [sind(30) * cosd(45), sind(30) * sind(45), cosd(30)];
b = [0;0;1];
psi = deg2rad(45);

v = cross(b,t);
s = norm(v);
c = dot(b,t);

phiB = psi;
uB = b;
uBhat = vector2ssMat(uB);

I = eye(3);

rotA = I+vector2ssMat(v)+(vector2ssMat(v)^2)*((1-c)/s^2);
rotB = I*cos(phiB)+uB*transpose(uB)*(1-cos(phiB))+uBhat*sin(phiB);

Rdes = rotA*rotB;
disp(Rdes);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake, actually u need to write the thrust vector t as column vector instead of the row vector. u can simply replace t with t' at all occurrences, it will solve the issue.